# How to set all groups equal to the group with the minimum group length (number of rows)?

Tags: r, dplyr

If I were to have a data frame as follows:

```
  subject-id activity label    timestamp          x         y          z
1       1600              A            0 -0.3647613  8.793503  1.0550842
2       1600              A          .05 -0.8797302  9.768784  1.0169983
3       1600              A          .10  2.0014954 11.109070   2.619156
4       1600              A          .15  0.4506226 12.651642 0.18455505
.
.
.
  subject-id activity label    timestamp           x          y          z
991      1600             B            0  1.37554930 15.3750460  2.9716187
992      1600             B          .05 -3.93443300 17.5387880  2.1100159
993      1600             B          .10 -0.08773804 12.7915650 -1.4541016
.
.
.
  subject-id activity label timestamp          x         y           z
24551       1601              A         0  4.7034090  9.127296  0.06404489
24552       1601              A       .05  5.3546320 15.635334 -0.62907650
24553       1601              A       .10  6.3997010 12.926893  0.45010993
```

My task now is to spread the data using pivot_wide() but the issue I am running into is that the groups I am working with have a different number of rows. I am grouping by activity label and subject id. Here is what I am trying:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(`activity label`, `subject-id`) %>% mutate(count = n())
```

or

```
df <- df %>% group_by(`activity label`, `subject-id`) %>% mutate(length.out = min(n()))
```

Basically, each group has a different number of rows. I am trying to find the group with the smallest number of rows and set every groups number of observations equal to the number of rows that the group with the minimum number of rows has.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(act, id) %>% 
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(count=min(count))` ?

Comment: @Edward I don't think that physically does anything because you ungroup before you alter the number of rows of each group

Comment: Ok. I guess I misunderstood. It was a question. The code physically assigns the minimum number of records in each group to each record. It doesnt alter anything in terms of actual records. Do you want to physically remove records??? If so, which ones? Keep all up to the minimum and then delete the rest?

Comment: I think slice may work. `df %>% group_by(act, id) %>% mutate(count = n()) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(count=min(count)) %>% group_by(act, id) %>% slice(seq_len(max(count)))`